# How can I remove a key in an SQL statement if its value is an empty string?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel

I need to remove a key from an SQL statement if its value is an empty string (**`''`**). For example, consider this SQL statement:

```sql
insert into
    `invoices_payments` (`invoice_id`, `finance_id`, `employee_id`, `shift_id`, `point_of_sale_id`, `debtor_id`, `creditor_id`, `debit`, `retroactive`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values
    (
        '101010044', '', '10100000', '1010000', '1', '70', '41', '89', '', '2023-09-27 10:22:25', '2023-09-27 10:22:25'
    )
;
```

I want it to become:

```sql
insert into
    `invoices_payments` (`invoice_id`, `employee_id`, `shift_id`, `point_of_sale_id`, `debtor_id`, `creditor_id`, `debit`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values
    (
        '101010044', '10100000', '1010000', '1', '70', '41', '89', '2023-09-27 10:22:25', '2023-09-27 10:22:25'
    )
;
```

I've tried the following PHP function, but it returns incorrect counts in the keys and values:

```php
function processSqlStatement($sqlStatement) {
    // Split the SQL statement into individual key-value pairs
    $pairs = explode(',', $sqlStatement);

    // Initialize an array to store valid key-value pairs
    $validPairs = [];

    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        // Check if the pair contains an empty single quote ('') or is empty after trimming
        if (strpos($pair, "''") === false && trim($pair) !== '') {
            // If not, add it to the valid pairs array
            $validPairs[] = trim($pair); // Trim to remove extra spaces
        }
    }

    // Join the valid pairs back into a single SQL statement using comma and space
    $modifiedSqlStatement = implode(', ', $validPairs);

    return $modifiedSqlStatement;
}
```

Comment: I think the biggest issue probably is that `// Split the SQL statement into individual key-value pairs
    $pairs = explode(',', $sqlStatement);` does nothing of the sort. Demo: https://3v4l.org/UfJn2

Comment: Could this problem not be fixed at source? What is generating the SQL statement in the first place?

Comment: why tag this as Laravel?

Comment: yes, finance_id and retroactive are also should gone as its values are single qoutes

Comment: tag is laravel becouse i want to write this logic using laravel so if it have a tip or a soultion

Comment: i capture every sql statment in the db ,and replace the bindings like  $sql = $query->sql;
                $bindings = $query->bindings;
                $time = $query->time
then $actualSql = vsprintf(str_replace('?', "'%s'", $sql), $bindings);

Comment: Ok. But that doesn't answer _why_ you need to do this. If you're using Laravel surely you should be using Laravel's ORM to write your SQL queries and parameterise them correctly. And whatever code you use, should check beforehand if a field contains `''` and exclude that from the query, or at least replace it with `null`, _before_ it's generated. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database

Comment: i'm doing this because we  want to  upload everything in the offline mode to the server when it becomes online so i'm storing the queries to run it again in the server  , the server like a collection area of all what happend in the offline from any soucrce offline , mysql replica isn't applicalbe because static ip non technical issue (more exepensive in that country ) invoces uniquiness have allready been handled

Comment: @ADyson what's your opinion, sir?

Comment: I think there is probably a better overall design approach to your offline mode idea, to be honest. Obviously I don't know all the requirements and your whole application design, but it all sounds a bit odd anyway. This is Laravel code you say, so presumably it runs on a webserver? And therefore it needs to be online in order to access the Laravel code? Or are you running that on a local webserver and then connecting to a central database online, or something like that?

Comment: yes , running that on a local webserver and then connecting to a central database online

Comment: Ok. That's a bizarre design but we'll put that to one side for now. I'd suggest rather than caching specific SQL queries for later uploading, you rather store a series of actions that the user has taken, and the accompany data. Perhaps you can serialise them or put them in JSON format. Like an event stream, basically. Then when the application is back online, whatever is processing its wake-up can run through the event stream, and perform each of the actions listed (which may of course involve generating and sending some SQL queries).

Comment: That way you avoid having to attempt re-create the SQL in this clunky and error-prone way. Instead, the application would perform the requested action, exactly as if it had been happening at the original time the user asked for it. I appreciate that may be a lot of work to redesign your application, but it should be more flexible overall anyway.

Comment: @ُEslamTalabeGaribeQoutbe I don't want to be rude or harsh with you, I would love to help you with your current design, but your issue is the design itself, so kill it. You could take a way better approach by using Jobs, have workers run jobs, and those jobs will be queries, but they will only be run when the database is online. Still, do you understand that you are running a "**local**" webserver? like, not sure what your application is, but goes against all standards and GDPR/security concerns in all aspects, like data, for example

Comment: You could also serialize a `Builder` with all the data and stuff you need, then deserialize the `Builder` and run it... but again, your issue is the design, it is easier to change it than to fix it in my honest opinion, but I also do not have all the requirements, so I cannot be of help apart from these comments

Comment: so messed up but it works https://3v4l.org/iDPpE

Comment: @TaurusSilver that looks like it took a bit of effort. You should add it as an Answer :-)

Comment: @ADyson i am too ashamed to add it as answer. Because is so messed up

Comment: @TaurusSilver the whole question and the OP's design is also messy. So it wouldn't be any worse than that! I doubt this problem has a neat solution anyway, without redesigning the whole approach as has been discussed earlier in these comments

Comment: @TaurusSilver maybe add backticks and single quotes to the output an then go for it! But I'm afraid the OP didn't bear with us...

Comment: many thanks to you ,sir ,you have saved my life @TaurusSilver

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above, that this is a somewhat clunky design approach, but wanted to try it anyways.

Using [kevinoo's parser](https://github.com/kevinoo/php-query-parser) the following does the magic:

```
<?php

require_once('./php-query-parser/src/Parser.php');
require_once('./php-query-parser/src/Statement/AbstractStatement.php');
require_once('./php-query-parser/src/Statement/InsertStatement.php');

use kevinoo\QueryParser\Parser;

$statement = "INSERT INTO `invoices_payments` (`invoice_id`, `finance_id`, `employee_id`, `shift_id`, `point_of_sale_id`, `debtor_id`, `creditor_id`, `debit`, `retroactive`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES ('101010044', '', '10100000', '1010000', '1', '70', '41', '89', '', '2023-09-27 10:22:25', '2023-09-27 10:22:25');";

$result = Parser::parse($statement);
$values = $result->getValues();

$fields_list = $values_list = [];
foreach($values[0] as $field=>$value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        $fields_list[] = "`{$field}`";
        $values_list[] = "'{$value}'";
    }
}

$fixed_statement = 'INSERT INTO `' . $result->getTableName() . '` (' . implode(', ', $fields_list) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', $values_list) . ');';

echo $fixed_statement;
```

Please note that "INSERT INTO" and "VALUES" needs to be all upper case for the parser being able to parse.